# jQuery Show and Hide with Speed Not Exiting For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, hide, show

I'm trying to show/hide a block of input fields based on the value of a  box. It works fine if I stick with show() and hide() but as soon as I put in a speed show(100) and hide(100) things break.

**What should happens is:**

- If value of select is an item found in an array then the block should show.
- If the value of the select is not an item found in an array then the block should not show.
- If the value of the select is an item found in an array and the block is visible nothing should happen.

---

**jsFiddle example code: http://jsfiddle.net/PkBg6/**

- Retail Individual should not show the block
- Employee should not show the block
- Everything else should show the block

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-control select double-margin-right span3">

    <label for="customerType">Customer Type</label>

    <select data-required="false" id="customerType">
        <option value="retailIndividual">Retail Individual</option>
        <option value="retailBusiness">Retail Business</option>
        <option value="dealer">Dealer</option>
        <option value="raceTeam">Race Team</option>
        <option value="membershipClub">Membership Club</option>
        <option value="employee">Employee</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix" id="groupMember" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-control text span3">
        <label for="businessName">Business Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="businessName" data-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-control text span3">
        <label for="department">Department</label>
        <input type="text" id="department" data-required="false" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.toggleFieldset = function(stringText, x) {
    var arrayText = stringText;

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
        if( $(this).val() == arrayText[i] ) {
            $(x).show();
            return;
        }

        else {
            $(x).hide();
        }
    }    

    $(this).on('change', function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) {
            if( $(this).val() == arrayText[i] ) {
                $(x).show(100);
                console.log('show');
                return;
            }

            else {
                $(x).hide(100);
                console.log('hide');
            }
        }
    });
};


$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#customerType').toggleFieldset(['retailBusiness', 'dealer', 'raceTeam', 'membershipClub'], '#groupMember');
});
```

Comment: Try `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. Also you forgot to declare `i` and `return` exits the function so the `else` is redundant.

Comment: @elclanrs I will declare the `i`. I tried `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` but I'm still having the same problem. I'm not sure how the `else` is redundant though because if nothing matches then it should execute the `else`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else clause is getting run when you don't want it to. When say dealer is selected it gets executed when compared to retailBusiness which hides it then it gets shown when it matches itself again. Here is the onchange function which worked for me.

```
$(this).on('change', function() {
    var match = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayText.length; i++) 
        if( $(this).val() == arrayText[i] ) 
            match = true;
    if( match ) {
       $(x).show(100);
       console.log('show'+arrayText[i]);
       return;
    }
    else {
       $(x).hide(100);
       console.log('hide'+arrayText[i]);
    }
});
```